# Does Genji's cocoon deal damages?

Tags: awesomenauts

I'm asking this because the description of the skill doesn't mention it, but when I hit an opponent with the cocoon, it clearly seems to hurt him.

> **Cocoon**
>
> Wrap your enemy in a solid cocoon, enemies in a cocoon will not be targetable.
>
> - Cooldown 9s
> - Duration 2s
> - Range 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I've just realized I opted for the *Misfortune cookie* enhancement, which reduces the target's health by 15%.
There are also two other buffs that can increase cocoon's damages: *Jagra eggs* (lifesteal 100%, damage + 15) and *Prefab cocoons* (damage +25).